# Shared application (Alias directive) permission issues

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, alias

I am using an Alias directory to use a content management system for multiple websites. It's like an application pool in IIS (for the Windows guys here).

While every website has its own user (I am using a VDS with DirectAdmin), and the CMS also has of course its own user, I now have permission issues because the CMS user needs read permissions in every website (= homedir).

How do I do that?

My situation:
`/home/myapp/cms with user 'myapp'` <- is attached to every website by an Alias directive

`/home/site1/public_html with user 'site1'`
`/home/site2/public_html with user 'site2'`

I have tried `chmod o+rX /home/myapp/cms`, but that didn't do the trick. Also chown is no solution, because it can handle only one single user.

**Update:** To illustrate this better, my site is showing the following error:

`Warning: require(/home/site1/public_html/includes/config.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/myapp/cms/index.php on line 2`

What means the 'shared application' hasn't have the sufficient right.

In this case I have also have done

`chmod o+rwX /home/site1/public_html/includes/config.php`

Of course 'myapp' and 'site1' is different in the real case. This is just an simplification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to change the permissions of the files inside `/home/myapp/cms` too. e.g. `chmod -R o+rX /home/myapp/cms`

Comment: Thanks for responding, but that didn't work. PHP displays the following error: `Warning: require(/home/site1/public_html/includes/config.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/myapp/cms/index.php on line 2`. What means the 'shared application' hasn't have the sufficient right. I also have done `chmod o+rwX /home/site1/public_html/includes/config.php`..

Comment: Look at what line2 of index.php is trying to do

Comment: My shared application is just requiring (including) the config file from the site (read). But it hasn't the needed rights. I think this is because the file owner is different, but that must be so (for FTP/DirectAdmin/etc).

Comment: If "other" has a read permission, and an execute permission on every parent directory of that directory, then it should be able to read it.

Comment: Thank you tumbleweed! I didn't consider that all parent directories do need the right permissions. 

So instead of `chmod -R o+rwX /home/somesite/public_html` I now tried `chmod -R o+rwX /home/somesite` and that did the trick.

But my second question now is: has all other 'website users' read/write permissions in this dir? Because that is not secure I guess..

Comment: Yes, you've given everyone write permissions. That's probably not a good idea :P